# Предикат для std::prioriry_queue

Tags: c++, очередь

Есть очередь с преоритетом, в которой лежит `QPair<int,int>` нужно сортировать эту очередь в зависимости от второго значения пары. Как правильно написать предикат?
По идее это функтор, возвращающий `bool`

```
struct Compare    
{   
    bool operator(const int& x, const int& y) const  
    { return x > y; }
};
```

Только как указать ему, что он должен работать со вторым значением пары?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Compare    
{   
    bool operator()(const QPair& p1, const QPair& p2) {
        return p1.second > p2.second; 
    }
};
```

или просто

```
[](const QPair& p1, const QPair& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; }
```